# multiple line to single line

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

```
FileReader f0 = new FileReader("1.html");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(f0);
while((temp1=br.readLine())!=null)
{
sb.append(temp1);
}
String para = sb.toString().replaceAll("<br>","\n");
String textonly = Jsoup.parse(para).text();
System.out.println(textonly);

FileWriter f1=new FileWriter("1.txt");
char buf1[] = new char[textonly.length()];
textonly.getChars(0,textonly.length(),buf1,0);

for(i=0;i<buf1.length;i++)
 {
 if(buf1[i]=='\n')
  f1.write("\r\n");
 f1.write(buf1[i]);
```

While making the new text file this code makes multiple line and I want that the text file should have only one line. How can I do this.

Comment: @Kazekage  "buf1" is not a string, it is a character. And after removing "\n" as you told it is not making only single line, it is giving the same result as prev.

Comment: @JB  Sir my code is compiling and giving result, but not in single line.

Comment: The "only" thing your code does is replace all "<br>" with a newline. If you want it to stop making new lines, either stop doing that and/or replace "<br>" with something else. (I know next to nothing of html but isn't "<br/>" also correct syntax? and if so should be handled the same way?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *even after removing all \n it is making multiple lines.*

I think the error is in the following code:

```
for( i = 0; i < buf1.length; i++ )
{
     if( buf1[ i ] == '\n' )
         f1.write( "\r\n" );
     f1.write( buf1[ i ] );
```

When a new line character `\n` is matched, you are writing `\r\n` to the file and again wring the same character to the file using `f1.write( buf1[ i ] )`. Using `else` will stop writing `\n` again to the file.

```
for( i = 0; i < buf1.length; i++ )
{
     if( buf1[ i ] == '\n' )
     {
         f1.write( "\r\n" );
     }
     else
     {
         f1.write( buf1[ i ] );
     }
     // ...
} // for
```

Alternatively use ternary operator to replace `\n` with `\r\n` while writing.

```
f1.write( buf1[ i ] == '\n' ? "\r\n" : buf1[ i ] );
```

Answer (score 2):

Stop writing newline characters \n to the file and you should stop having multiple lines being made.

Comment: even after removing all \n it is making multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't <\br> and \n same kind of thing? if you do this ,there will be no change in your text.
You need to replace <\br> with an space.

```
String para = sb.toString().replaceAll("<br>"," ");
```